# Parsing Push notification iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

trying ot parse the push I geting with my app.

but i get some problems here:

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] objectForKey:@"aps"];
 NSLog(@"resourcePath: %@", resourcePath);
```

NSLog

```
{
        alert = cb;
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
        url = cxb;  }
```

I NSLog it as String... how to get the URL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its a dictionary Object. Get object for url key. Like this:

```
NSString *resourcePathURL = [[[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"url"] ;

NSLog(@"URL : %@",resourcePathURL);
```